# Difference between "beverage" and "drink"

Tags: meaning, nouns, differences, food

I am not sure when to use "beverage" and when to use "drink". I have read a bit on Google, both words come under alcoholic and non-alcoholic category of drinks.

Comment: I have the impression "beverage" is not a word you use in colloquial language. It is a word you find on lists of drinks/beverages in restaurants.

Comment: @rogermue In British English it can be used very much in colloquial speech. There is a way of speaking which is 'faux-fancy' for want of a better term and that you use to be faintly amusing amongst friends. So if it is your turn to buy a round you might say something like, 'Can I interest any of you fine gents in another beverage?', rather than 'who wants another drink?' Generally in colloquial terms 'beverages' are alcoholic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "beverage" when you want to sound formal. Use "drink" when you don't mind that it could be confused with the verb.

While they are synonyms, each has its own idioms. "Adult beverage" and "Drinks are on me" would both sound weird with the words swapped.

Comment: What for the love of Jesus, is an "adult beverage"? Does it contain bodily fluids?

Comment: An ["adult beverage"](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/adult-beverage) is an [alcoholic beverage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adult+beverage) since you must be an adult to legally consume it.  It may contain bodily fluids if, say after realizing you could have easily looked this up yourself, you go and cry in your beer. @JoostKiefte

Comment: Although I have heard people say "adult drinks" before...

Comment: FWIW i've never encountered the phrase "adult beverage".  "alcoholic beverage", yes, but not "adult".